# Why i'm not able to get the return value from model to controller in node js project?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, model-view-controller

I'm trying to implement a `Nodejs project in MVC pattern`.

My project folder structure is:

[image]

My `controller` userController.js looks like:

```
var usersModel = require('../models/users');

module.exports.list=function(req,res){
    var rows = usersModel.getAll();
    console.log(rows);
    res.render('index',{
        title:"Customers - Node.js",
        data:rows
    });
}
```

My `model` users.js is like:

```
var connection = require('../config');    
module.exports = {
    getAll: function() {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, rows) {
            console.log(rows); // its showing the records in cmd
            if (err) 
                console.log("Error in Query:", err);
            else 
                return rows;
        })
    }
};
```

And the `Route` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var userController = require('../controllers/userController');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', userController.list);

module.exports = router;
```

Here, the resultant rows from the model method i'm not able to get in the controller. Whats the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connection.query(...) is asynchronous and therefore res.render() is called before the value is retrieved form the database. You should look into promises, callback functions or async await in order to handle these cases. You will use them very often in node.

For example, to return a promise in your getAll function:

```
getAll: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, rows) {
            console.log(rows); // its showing the records in cmd
            if (err) 
                reject(err)
            else 
                resolve(rows);
        })
    })
}
```

And modify your controller for the return values:

```
function(req,res) {
    usersModel.getAll()
        .then(function(rows) {
            console.log(rows);
            res.render('index',{
                title:"Customers - Node.js",
                data:rows
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Handle error here
        })
}
```

Comment: +1 for [You should look into promises, callback functions or async await in order to handle these cases]